# WebOS Error: All configured authentication methods failed

Tags: jquery, html, dom, virtualbox, webos

I'm trying to run a first app on the LG's WebOS emulator v3.0 on Ubuntu 14.04 system.

I followed the steps as given in this [link](https://developer.lge.com/webOSTV/develop/web-app/getting-started/building-your-first-web-app-webos-tv/)

### Steps Followed from WebOS CLI

Commands run:

> ares-generate first-app -v
>
> ares-package first-app

I have also run the webOS TV Emulator. However, I am unable to run the ares-install command on the package that is created.

> ares-install com.sash.dev_0.0.1_all.ipk

### Verbose Log Output

[Log File Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2lCmt16L_r3T1VTeGtZd1JKY0E)

Does WebOS not work with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS version as per the [Download SDK](https://developer.lge.com/webOSTV/sdk/web-sdk/) link of the WebOS, Ubuntu 14.04 is not present in the system requirement section.

I have tried using passphrase and security key for authentication.

For passphrase:

> I have input the user's password.

For security key:

> Used the Default File for ssh private key [webos_emul] and no passphrase for the default file.

I'm guessing that there shouldn't be passphrase for ssh private key file, as I'm able to open the file without any passphrase.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed the Issue by changing the username to developer.

Lesson Learnt: Don't use your username but that of the default username as created by the WebOS Cli.

Comment: it was nice to have some more information. What username do you need to change??